# GCP: Can Functions that use Serverless VPC Access also enjoy Private Google Access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-networking

I want a Cloud Function on GCP to connect to a Google API (eg, `compute.googleapis.com`) *privately*.  That is, not over the internet.  I also want this Cloud Function to egress *all traffic* into a VPC through a [Serverless VPC Accessor](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options#serverless-vpc-access).

For VMs to connect privately to Google APIs, one enables [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access) for the subnet that the VM lives on.  But, for Functions, the "serverless connector" is not a subnet *per se*, and so one can't enable Private Google Access for this connector. With Private Google Access, the call to a Google API originating from a Function eventually heads out the default internet gateway to the public internet.

How can I get my Function to make calls to Google APIs privately after egressing onto my VPC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are in the Google network, you never go to the internet for reaching a Google service. In the worst case, because it's not in the same region, you go into the Google global fiber network.

If you are in the same region, you stay inside it.

**Thus, your call are private by default**. You don't have Google Cloud Functions to enforce this, it's by default.

But, if you prefer to be sure, you can use the [private DNS of Google by adding `private`](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#config) like this: `compute.private.googleapis.com`

Comment: Hm.  I'm not so sure about that privacy - or, at least I'd like a way to prove it out.
First, when I resolve the hostname for `compute.googleapis.com` from within a Cloud Function, I get back a public IP address.
Secondly, I thought Functions run on a different stack than the frontends for these APIs, and so do not have a direct route.

Comment: Public IP doesn't go to Internet! Router are there for routing the flow smartly inside the network. Did you try to perform something similar to trace route?

Comment: That's an interesting question - I'm afraid traceroute isn't giving us much to work with:

traceroute to compute.googleapis.com (172.217.212.95), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  172.217.212.95 (172.217.212.95)  0.799 ms * *

Comment: I don't know how to demonstrate it. I don't find any documentation very clear on this. Only this [Google blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/google-cloud-network-connectivity-options-explained) where all the Google stuff are in the same "blue cloud". Or [here](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#interaction-pga) where NAT definition is by passed in case of Google apis calls. (and  you can configure NAT with Google Cloud Functions). Do you have any Google contact on your side?